# QuickSort not quick enough

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, quicksort

note: this is related to a homework question

I'm trying to sort a LinkedList type WordPair (WordPair contains string wordA, and wordB) of a variable size, smaller ones work fine, but when I try to sort a list with thousands of words, if freezes every time without fail, and this is the second sort method I've tried. I've heard of garbage collecting but have no idea how to use it or if it would even help. Does anyone know how to make this method more efficient without changing the data types?

also if you run this you'll notice the descending method does not work, i thought all i'd have to do is copy the ascending and swap the two greater that or less than symbols in the partition functions, but i guess not. so if you could point me in the right direction to fix that as well, it'd be greatly appreciated.

this is my Quicksort class...

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Quicksort{

 private Partition p = new Partition();

public void sortAscending(LinkedList<WordPair> dictionary, int min, int max){
int pivot;

if(min < max){
  pivot = p.partitionAscending(dictionary, min, max);
  sortAscending(dictionary, min, pivot-1);
  sortAscending(dictionary, pivot+1, max);

  System.gc();
 }
}

public void sortDescending(LinkedList<WordPair> dictionary, int min, int max){
int pivot;

if(min < max){
  pivot = p.partitionDescending(dictionary, min, max);
  sortAscending(dictionary, min, pivot-1);
  sortAscending(dictionary, pivot+1, max);

  System.gc();
 }
}

public static void main(String[] args){

 }
}
```

and my partition class...

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Partition{

 public static int partitionAscending(LinkedList<WordPair> dictionary, int min, int max){
WordPair pivotpoint = dictionary.get(min);
int left = min;
int right = max;

while(left < right){
  while (dictionary.get(left).getWordA().compareToIgnoreCase(pivotpoint.getWordA()) <= 0 && left < right)
    left++;

  while (dictionary.get(right).getWordA().compareToIgnoreCase(pivotpoint.getWordA()) > 0)
    right--;

  if (left < right)
    swap(dictionary, left, right);

  System.gc();
}

swap(dictionary, min, right);

return right;
}

public static int partitionDescending(LinkedList<WordPair> dictionary, int min, int max){
WordPair pivotpoint = dictionary.get(min);
int left = min;
int right = max;

while(left < right){
  while (dictionary.get(left).getWordA().compareToIgnoreCase(pivotpoint.getWordA()) >= 0 && left < right)
    left++;

  while (dictionary.get(right).getWordA().compareToIgnoreCase(pivotpoint.getWordA()) < 0)
    right--;

  if (left < right)
    swap(dictionary, left, right);

  System.gc();
}

    swap(dictionary, min, right);

    return right;
  }

  private static void swap (LinkedList<WordPair> dictionary, int index1, int index2)
  {
    WordPair temp = dictionary.get(index1);
    dictionary.set(index1, dictionary.get(index2));
    dictionary.set(index2, temp);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){

  }
}
```

Comment: LinkedList.get(idx) => O(n); so it could be the reason if you use large lists and avoid System.gc();

Comment: Descending does not work because you call sortAscending in your sortDescending method

Comment: @MarcoAcierno - so how else would i go about getting that value? and thanks for the tip, i got rid of the System.gc();

Comment: @andy - thank you, i feel retarded now, idk how i missed that.

Comment: Use an ArrayList? it uses an array

Comment: @MarcoAcierno - it doesn't use an array at all. It's a list of a custom object that contains two seperate string objects. So an array of that object is just as useful if not less than the linkedlist because its not a string object, which is what the sort is based off of. I'm sorting the objects based off of wordA in each object.

Comment: Nothing will change your you, just the speed of get method. ArrayList source: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java (p.s your elements will be limited by Integer.MAX_INT size, but i don't think it could be a problem)